# Handling ARGF.read in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using following lines of code in my ruby program on ubuntu:

```
data=ARGF.read

if data.length != 0

      .....

end
```

The program runs fine when I run as "cat file.txt | ruby test.rb", however, I am unable to handle following issues:

1. When run as "cat | ruby test.rb", the program goes into endless loop.
2. When run as "ruby test.rb", the program goes into endless loop.
3. When run as "cat file1.txt | ruby test.rb", the program gives "cat: file1.txt: No such file or directory" error.

Any input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: well, can't reproduce your "infinite" loop scenario, but instead of checking data length, check data presence (`if data` instead of `if data.length != 0`). Maybe it'll fix _some_ issues.

Comment: "When run as "cat file1.txt | ruby test.rb", the program gives "cat: file1.txt: No such file or directory" error." - well, you don't have `file1.txt` and it is `cat` who's complaining. Your script is not even touched.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio Tulentsev, I want to handle cat complain. How can I do that? Also I have tried with if data but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `ARGF` is used for. `ARGF.read` gives all the data of all the files passed as arguments.

When you don't give any input file, it is waiting for you to give the input through stdin. Since, you are in Ubuntu, you could just press (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) which would end the stream and then you could process the `data` normally.